# Get all associated EOS accounts linked to a public key using javascript using a public endpoint?

Tags: accounts, account-name, api, public-key, json

I want to return all the associated EOS accounts that is linked to a specific public key in JSON format for my javascript dapp. Currently I can paste the pub key into: https://eosflare.io/key/EOS6M1m2KBk8BF6uwEnRyjXvpBTUxqLfMUZALzsUGtrHvcEHTYFi1

But there is no JSON output. How can I just a **RELIABLE** EOS endpoint to do these queries to get a JSON output of all the accounts associated to a pub key?

Do I use one of these endpoints? https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can query that api end points as i have performed query on this api from  https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/ with post parameter `{"public_key":"EOS6M1m2KBk8BF6uwEnRyjXvpBTUxqLfMUZALzsUGtrHvcEHTYFi1"}`
and api url is

```
https://eos.greymass.com:443/v1/history/get_key_accounts
```

I am not sure but i think this can be done by eosjs also.

Here is code for js

```
var request = require('request');


    var Body = {"public_key":"EOS6M1m2KBk8BF6uwEnRyjXvpBTUxqLfMUZALzsUGtrHvcEHTYFi1"};
      //options for liverate api of btc,eth and eos
    var options = {
        url: 'https://eos.greymass.com:443/v1/history/get_key_accounts',
        json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
        body: Body

    };

    function callback1(error, response, body) 
    {
        console.log("in jssss");
       console.log(body);
    }        
    request.post(options, callback1);
```

Comment: Do you have a js sample code I can test in the chrome console?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ i have edited my answer have a look at it for js code

Comment: what is require('request')? is that a library I need to fetch?

Comment: It's a node module to post data on url for more you can find out here https://www.npmjs.com/package/requesthttps://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: cant i just use pure js instead of external library?

Comment: yes you can do that also